# FFMPEG Error!!! moov atom not found Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to combine chunks of reversed videos but this error hits me.
I have seen many solutions but none of them worked.

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xe8db4600] moov atom not found
/storage/emulated/0/Movies/VideoPartsReverse/reverse_video0.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

This is the command for concatenation.

```
[-i, /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VideoPartsReverse/reverse_video1.mp4, -i, /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VideoPartsReverse/reverse_video0.mp4, -filter_complex, [0:v0] [0:a0] [1:v1] [1:a1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a], -movflags, faststart, -preset, ultrafast, -map, [v], -map, [a], /storage/emulated/0/Movies/reverse_video.mp4]
```

Even adding this didn't help `-movflags, faststart`

this is the detailed error message

```
mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xe8db4600 moov atom not found Invalid data found when processing input
```

Answer (score 2):

`moov atom not found` can be a pain. because you have to stream the content and recreate an mp4 in order to get this metadata created.
For Windows, follow the instructions from here:
https://www.videohelp.com/software/recover-mp4-to-h264

> Step 1: Use any good previous file with the same resolution and bitrate to generate the header files
>
> Step 2: Recover streams from the corrupted file
>
> Step 3: Use any other utility (Yamb or ffmpeg for example)
> to recreate the MP4/MOV file from the streams (recovered.h264 and recovered.aac).

Comment: I have tried the solution above, not worked for me. However, I found another better solution in that website https://www.videohelp.com/software/MP4-Repair-untrunc-GUI. This software integrates the famous untrunc and ffmpeg into a GUI version, thus can repair the videos in a very simple manner.