# How to repair corrupted mp4 video?

Tags: video, mp4, video-processing, corruption, resolver

I have a 7 GB mp4 video, but when I put it to Windows Media Player the screen goes black and you do not hear anything, an error comes out that says "There was a problem playing the file in Windows Media Player.".

I have tried many programs such as wondershare or rowing among others, but all of them to work properly must be paid to others that in the demos also gave me problems, where they told me to change the sample video because it does not work, but even changing it 5 or 6 times it still didn’t work.

I have also tested the way that is done by terminal where you put the command `recover_mp4.exe 0031.mp4 --analyze`, that if I do not do it wrong is put to the first video mp4 that is good and then a bad one with the command that gives you after the first, I don’t know what else to do.

Here is the result of analyzing the video metadata using `ffprobe`:

```
D:\CorruptVideos>ffprobe 0282.mp4
ffprobe version 2023-02-16-git-aeceefa622-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
  libavcodec     60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavformat    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavdevice    60.  0.100 / 60.  0.100
  libavfilter     9.  2.100 /  9.  2.100
  libswscale      7.  0.100 /  7.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001c25eaeaec0] moov atom not found
0282.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Output from the command I put in the first step of recover_mp4

```
D:\CorruptVideos>recover_mp4.exe 0031.mp4 --analyze
recover_mp4 v1.92 (C) 2011-2017 Dmitry Vasilyev <slydiman@mail.ru>
http://slydiman.me

Analyzing file '0031.mp4':

'ftyp' 0x0 [32] Major Brand: 'qt  ', Minor Version: 0x20050300
  Compatible brands: 'qt  ', 'ARRI'
'wide' 0x20 [33554368]
  Unprocessed 33554360 bytes
'mdat' 0x1FFFFE0 [2351026184]
'moov' 0x8E21CFE8 [77973]
  'mvhd' 0x8E21CFF0 [108] Movie Header: Time scale 25, Duration 1945 (77.8 sec)
    Rate 1, Volume 1
    Creating time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
    Modification time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
    Next Track ID: 4
  'trak' 0x8E21D05C [13693]
    'tkhd' 0x8E21D064 [92] Track #1, Duration 1945
      Resolution: 2048x1152
      Creating time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
      Modification time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
    'tapt' 0x8E21D0C0 [68]
      Unprocessed 60 bytes
    'edts' 0x8E21D104 [36]
      Unprocessed 28 bytes
    'mdia' 0x8E21D128 [13489]
      'mdhd' 0x8E21D130 [32] Media Header: Time scale 25, Duration 1945 (77.8 sec)
        Creating time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
        Modification time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
      'hdlr' 0x8E21D150 [58] Component Type: 'mhlr', Subtype: 'vide', Apple Video Media Handler
      'minf' 0x8E21D18A [13391]
        'vmhd' 0x8E21D192 [20]
        'hdlr' 0x8E21D1A6 [57] Component Type: 'dhlr', Subtype: 'alis', Apple Alias Data Handler
        'dinf' 0x8E21D1DF [36]
          'dref' 0x8E21D1E7 [28]
            'alis' 0x8E21D1F7 [12]
              Unprocessed 4 bytes 00 00 00 01
        'stbl' 0x8E21D203 [13270]
          'stsd' 0x8E21D20B [190]
            'apch' 0x8E21D21B [174]
              Unprocessed 166 bytes
          'stts' 0x8E21D2C9 [24] Time-to-Sample[1] (#: Count * Duration):
             0: 1945 * 1
          'stsc' 0x8E21D2E1 [40] Sample-to-Chunk[2] (#: FirstChunk / SamplesPerChunk / SampleDescIndex):
             0: 1 / 3 / 1
             1: 649 / 1 / 1
          'stsz' 0x8E21D309 [7800] Sample Size[1945] (#: Sample Size):
             0: 0x9b000
             1: 0xbd000
             2: 0xc0000
             3: 0xd3000
             4: 0xfa000
             5: 0x10d000
             6: 0x10d000
             7: 0x10d000
             8: 0x10d000
             9: 0x10d000
            10: 0x10d000
            ...
          'co64' 0x8E21F181 [5208] Chunk Offset64 [649] (#: Chunk Offset):
             0: 0x2048000
             1: 0x2260000
             2: 0x253a000
             3: 0x2861000
             4: 0x2bac000
             5: 0x2ed3000
             6: 0x31fa000
             7: 0x3521000
             8: 0x386c000
             9: 0x3b93000
            10: 0x3eba000
            ...
  'trak' 0x8E2205D9 [1893]
    'tkhd' 0x8E2205E1 [92] Track #2, Duration 1945
      Creating time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
      Modification time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
    'edts' 0x8E22063D [36]
      Unprocessed 28 bytes
    'mdia' 0x8E220661 [1757]
      'mdhd' 0x8E220669 [32] Media Header: Time scale 48000, Duration 3734400 (77.8 sec)
        Creating time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
        Modification time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
      'hdlr' 0x8E220689 [58] Component Type: 'mhlr', Subtype: 'soun', Apple Sound Media Handler
      'minf' 0x8E2206C3 [1659]
        'smhd' 0x8E2206CB [16]
        'hdlr' 0x8E2206DB [57] Component Type: 'dhlr', Subtype: 'alis', Apple Alias Data Handler
        'dinf' 0x8E220714 [36]
          'dref' 0x8E22071C [28]
            'alis' 0x8E22072C [12]
              Unprocessed 4 bytes 00 00 00 01
        'stbl' 0x8E220738 [1542]
          'stsd' 0x8E220740 [130]
            'in24' 0x8E220750 [114] Sound Sample v1, 2ch, 16 bits, 48000 Hz
              'wave' 0x8E220784 [38]
                'frma' 0x8E22078C [12]
                  Unprocessed 4 bytes 69 6E 32 34
                'enda' 0x8E220798 [10]
                  Unprocessed 2 bytes 00 01
                {0000} 0x8E2207A2 [8]
              'chan' 0x8E2207AA [24]
                Unprocessed 16 bytes
          'stts' 0x8E2207C2 [24] Time-to-Sample[1] (#: Count * Duration):
             0: 3734400 * 1
          'stsc' 0x8E2207DA [40] Sample-to-Chunk[2] (#: FirstChunk / SamplesPerChunk / SampleDescIndex):
             0: 1 / 23040 / 1
             1: 163 / 1920 / 1
          'stsz' 0x8E220802 [20] Sample Size[0] (#: Sample Size = 0x1):
          'co64' 0x8E220816 [1320] Chunk Offset64 [163] (#: Chunk Offset):
             0: 0x2000000
             1: 0x2024000
             2: 0x2b88000
             3: 0x3848000
             4: 0x4508000
             5: 0x51c8000
             6: 0x5e88000
             7: 0x6b48000
             8: 0x7808000
             9: 0x84c8000
            10: 0x9188000
            ...
  'trak' 0x8E220D3E [621]
    'tkhd' 0x8E220D46 [92] Track #3, Duration 1945
      Resolution: 2048x1152
      Creating time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
      Modification time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
    'edts' 0x8E220DA2 [36]
      Unprocessed 28 bytes
    'mdia' 0x8E220DC6 [453]
      'mdhd' 0x8E220DCE [32] Media Header: Time scale 25, Duration 1945 (77.8 sec)
        Creating time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
        Modification time: 2023/02/11 2:57:54
      'hdlr' 0x8E220DEE [56] Component Type: 'mhlr', Subtype: 'tmcd', Time Code Media Handler
      'minf' 0x8E220E26 [357]
        'gmhd' 0x8E220E2E [86]
          Unprocessed 78 bytes
        'hdlr' 0x8E220E84 [57] Component Type: 'dhlr', Subtype: 'alis', Apple Alias Data Handler
        'dinf' 0x8E220EBD [36]
          'dref' 0x8E220EC5 [28]
            'alis' 0x8E220ED5 [12]
              Unprocessed 4 bytes 00 00 00 01
        'stbl' 0x8E220EE1 [170]
          'stsd' 0x8E220EE9 [70]
            'tmcd' 0x8E220EF9 [54]
              Unprocessed 46 bytes
          'stts' 0x8E220F2F [24] Time-to-Sample[1] (#: Count * Duration):
             0: 1 * 1945
          'stsc' 0x8E220F47 [28] Sample-to-Chunk[1] (#: FirstChunk / SamplesPerChunk / SampleDescIndex):
             0: 1 / 1 / 1
          'stsz' 0x8E220F63 [20] Sample Size[0] (#: Sample Size = 0x4):
          'stco' 0x8E220F77 [20] Chunk Offset[1] (#: Chunk Offset):
             0: 0x1fffff0
    'udta' 0x8E220F8B [32]
      'kgtt' 0x8E220F93 [20]
        Unprocessed 12 bytes
      Unprocessed 4 bytesERROR: Please report to the developer!
```

And the output of the second recover_mp4 step, after making the first

```
D:\CorruptVideos>recover_mp4.exe 0282.mp4 recovered.h264 recovered.aac
recover_mp4 v1.92 (C) 2011-2017 Dmitry Vasilyev <slydiman@mail.ru>
http://slydiman.me

Writing H264 video file 'recovered.h264'...
Cannot open file 'video.hdr'
Video=0.000
'recovered.h264' created, size 0 (0.000%)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it and without money or very little?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe a silly question but have you tried [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/)?

Comment: Yes, I’ve tried it and it doesn’t work either, it stays with the black screen, without sound and it doesn’t mark the time that the video lasts, even when converting it and trying again didn’t work either.

Comment: You may analyze the metadata for the file and add it to your question, for example use `ffprobe` (part of [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)). The output may also help you to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: I just did but haven’t figured out why it doesn’t work or a possible solution

Comment: @Bernat have you tried these VLC settings? https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=485671#p485671

Comment: Okay, so at least it is able to detect one video, one audio and a data stream. What errors are logged to console when you `ffplay` the video?

Comment: @philipphutterer, I’ve got the wrong video, the one I analyzed earlier is fine, now I analyze the one that’s wrong, I’m sorry

Comment: @PeterT, now yes, after you gave me the link I did but nothing has changed, continue with the screen in black, without sound and without indicating anything.

Comment: Ok with this error message I think you can find existing threads, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406126/ffmpeg-error-moov-atom-not-found-invalid-data-found-when-processing-input/65657023#65657023) - I don't know if this exact one will help, but IMO this is a common problem.

Comment: @philipphutterer, I still do not work, I have followed the steps I said in the link you put, and also the two different links I had inside, but it does not work and all the time I get error.
I think the problem I have in the first command I put because it does not come out as it says it has to be in the links.

Comment: @Bernat Are you using a 32-bit OS by any chance? Is your file supposed to be 7 gig or is it supposed to be 2.3 gig? From what I see, the metadata (MOOV) comes **after** the media's actual A/V data (MDAT). Some players' codes may not be searching that far ahead. The fix would be to move the metadata to the front (so MOOV section comes **before** MDAT section). You need to tell us which programming languages you know how to modify bytes or arrays with, then advice could be given on how to code a solution.

Comment: @VC.Uno, I’m using a 64-bit operating system, and in theory the 0282.mp4 video is 3.92 gigabytes, I know about quite a few programming languages so it wouldn’t be a problem but I don’t know about modifying bytes or arrays, I can learn how to modify them if I know how to do it.

Comment: @Bernat Please use `@VC.One` if you use the **Uno** it does not notify me. It's only now that I see your notice. Do you still need advice to try repair the MP4 file? Did you research the MP4 structure?